# Don't offer me any explanation(explanations?)

Tags: exam-questions

> Don't offer me any explanation now, I'm not going to accept it today.

I don't have the link but I remember reading in an answer on SE that if the noun is countable it will be in plural form after *any* so going by that is it incorrect to use *explanation* in the above sentence or there is any exception here ?

Comment: `Any Explanation` & `more explanations`

Comment: If you use _it_, you need singular. If there are more than one explanation, use plural and _them_. I believe @Chiru is incorrect. You can use Any with singular and plural: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112996/any-followed-by-singular-or-plural-countable-nouns.